# Talend considering excel header with a \n as 2 separate rows

Tags: excel, talend

I am trying to import an excel in Talend where some of the Header values consist of the enter(\n) key. E.g A Header contains 
"Abc
(Date)
" as a header row. I tried giving the file as a csv giving the Field Separator as "," and the row separator as "\n".In the escape char settings, I have given the Text Enclosure as "\"".

Even then, My header is getting split into 2 rows as "Abc" and "(Date)". I cant set the number of headers to 2 since not all headers have data separated by the enter key.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I can't really work out what your example file looks like. Could you host an example somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this Jira, this was an issue in previous versions of the product, but should be fixed in version 5.2.2 or greater:

https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-25622